# Need example of listening for property change messages

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I have two properties of type int in my view model that broadcast their property changed events in the classic way:

```
RaisePropertyChanged(MyPropertyPropertyName, oldValue, value, true);
```

These properties are both of type int, so my listener begins with:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<PropertyChangedMessage<int>>( ????? );
```

How do I create a listener for *propertyA* separate from a listener for *propertyB*?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll need to use a switch statement.  After all Messenger's purpose is to broadcast messages.

```
        MessengerInstance.Register<PropertyChangedMessage<int>>(this, IntReceiver);

        RaisePropertyChanged("Test 1", 0, 1, true);
        RaisePropertyChanged("Test 2", 0, 2, true);
    }

    private void IntReceiver(PropertyChangedMessage<int> n)
    {
        switch (n.PropertyName)
        {
            case "Test 1":
                Debug.WriteLine("Test1:" + n.NewValue);
                break;
            case "Test 2":
                Debug.WriteLine("Test2:" + n.NewValue);
                break;
        }
    }
```